# Can Self extracting rar file (SFX) be used to automatically install malicious software?

Tags: malware, social-engineering

Self extracting RAR files can be made containing dangerous files but can these SFX files be used as a tool for social engineering attacks (email attachments or on promotional CD-ROM etc.) to trick a user to install malicious software (RAT or keyloggers)? or are these SFX files detectable by security software?

Comment: How does the recipient knows at all that this is an SFX and not some malicious program claiming to be an SFX? Just because the sender claims that this is SFX?

Comment: @Steffen, I guess the recipient never knows! Some email service providers do not allow attaching EXE files but if it is hidden inside a SFX file this limitation can be bypassed. Lets imagine an SFX rar file containing malware or RAT and is titled "New products catalogue" to trick an employee to extract it. This might be as dangerous as .EXE files just disguised.

Comment: @PMD an SFX is an executable file by default, so if the e-mail provider blocks exe files it would get blocked. As far as I know standard archives such as zip or rar aren't self-extractible so there's no way to make an evil SFX with the rar extension.

Comment: @PMD: SFX is an executable not only by default but always. The main idea behind [SFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-extracting_archive) is that it is not only the archive but that it includes the program for unpacking so that the recipient does not need any extra program for unpacking (e.g. *self* extracting). This program is in no way restricted, i.e. can also be malicious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As SFX are executable program files they can at least be infected by a malware/virus/trojan, like any other program. Such malwares can be used to install malicious software, directly or indirectly (by dowloading something, for example).

I don't know whether there are specific exploits tied to SFX though. The above is general to executable files. The only SFX vulnerability I found so far is [this one](http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2006-3912/), which doesn't prove there is no more harmful one.

Reading this link from RARLab.com can be interesting for more details: http://www.rarlab.com/vuln_sfx_html.htm

Also, when you wish to unpack a SFX, nothing prevents you from opening it with WinRAR instead of executing it as a program. This way the unpacking executable part of the archive won't be executed. This is just a first level of protection though as once again I'm not sure whether SFX-specific exploits exist.

Regarding the detection of such malwares, it is all up to your antivirus. Basically, they won't be detectable at the very beginning ("the first day") but will probably be after the next "malware definition files" update of your antivirus. (More about that in this other answer: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/140450/126594)